# SQL in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
insert into BOOK values(&bid, '&title', '&pub', &year);
```

I am getting an error when I run the query in oracle 10g, this is the error message i am getting:

> ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Comment: some variable doesn't have a valid substitute value

Comment: Even before that error - you probably meant `&title` and `&pub` to be input variables. If you enclose them in single quotes, they are no longer treated as variables. You don't need the quotes; if you input strings for those two variables, they are inserted as strings into your table. Then: did you, in fact, give any values to your variables? If you don't know how to do that, you will need to tell us what front-end you are using, since they all have different ways of assigning values to bind variables. That is: are you using SQL\*Plus, SQL Developer, Toad, ... ?

Comment: Add the line "SET DEFINE OFF" before you execute your SQL. Otherwise it will be prompting you for &title and &pub, which are constants, not variables.

Comment: What are the datatypes of bid, title , pub and year?

Answer (score 0):

By default, SQL Plus treats '&' as a special character that begins a substitution string. So when you run this query oracle will consider bid, title, pub, year as bind variables and prompt you to enter the values for these variables. Enter the values for them it will replace the values and inserts the record into the database.

If you want to turn of the default behavior you can use the following command

```
SQL> set define off
```

Once you want to turn on the default behavior use this command

```
SQL> set define on
```

Hope this helps!